# Cronjobs Plesk 10.2.0 Not working

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks, plesk

Currently I am trying to get a cronjob working in Parallels Plesk Panel 10.2.0.

The script I want to run is on a subdomain.

I've tried a lot of options in the command line, but nothing is working.

Tried:

`/usr/bin/php /home/httpd/vhosts/subdomain.domain.com/httpdocs/file.php`

`/usr/bin/wget -O - -q http://www.subdomain.domain.com/file.php`

`/usr/curl http://subdomain.domain.com/controller/action`

`/var/www/vhosts/subdomain.domain.com/httpdocs/file.php`

`php /var/www/vhosts/subdomain.domain.com/httpdocs/file.php`

None of the above work. Also in the schedule task settings under `Send notification messages from scheduler to e-mail address` I filled in my email address but I won't get any emails.

Please help me, Thanks!

**EDIT**

My setting `Access to the server over SSH` are set to `Forbidden` I don't know if this can be a reason

Comment: Have you set the correct permissions on `file.php`?

Comment: In file.php: `<?php mail('my@email.com', 'Cronjob', 'Cronjob working'); ?>`

Comment: Yes that is great, but are the correct operating system file permissions set on `file.php`?

Comment: does `file.php` have any includes in it? I just set up a cron today and the include paths in my script were relative and that's why the cron failed for me.

Comment: Nope, like i said in these commands before. File.php only contains `<?php mail('my@email.com', 'Cronjob', 'Cronjob working'); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed this tutorial which given me positive results for setting up a cron job in parallels plesk.

The sentence which worked for me is:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/vhosts/bonusgo.com/httpdocs/cron.php
```

Dont forget to set the email address for cron jobs messages/alerts, in your hosting admin panel

Check the following url: [Set up a Magento cron job in plesk](http://www.e-commercewebdesign.co.uk/blog/magento-tutorials/setting-up-a-cron-job-for-magento.php)

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I already have it working. I used `wget -O /dev/null http://subdomain.domain.com/controller/method`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Parallels, the following SHH command is required to allow full access permissions as cron tasks run using a restricted access rights

> /usr/local/psa/bin/server_pref -u -crontab-secure-shell "/bin/sh"

And to revert the access permissions

> /usr/local/psa/bin/server_pref -u -crontab-secure-shell ""